# TA-Lib error when installing requrements.txt file on windows

Tags: python, ta-lib

I'm following a tutorial online which needs Python installed and a bunch of requirements I have managed to install them however when I try and install my requrements.txt file on to my venv I'm getting a stream of errors and warnings on TA-Lib. I've installed C++ as well but only when installing this requirements text do I get these errors.

```
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\programming\bot\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n7ad74zp\\ta-lib_1088777ae08747e18e950c7d1e1c3643\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n7ad74zp\\ta-lib_1088777ae08747e18e950c7d1e1c3643\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-us4n0edm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\programming\bot\include\site\python3.10\TA-Lib'
         cwd: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n7ad74zp\ta-lib_1088777ae08747e18e950c7d1e1c3643\
    Complete output (518 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\abstract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\deprecated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\stream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\test_abstract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\test_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\test_func.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\test_pandas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\test_stream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    copying talib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib
    running build_ext
    building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\talib
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\ta-lib\c\include -Ic:\programming\bot\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\programming\bot\include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tctalib/_ta_lib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\talib/_ta_lib.obj
    _ta_lib.c
    c:\programming\bot\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    talib/_ta_lib.c(6885): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    talib/_ta_lib.c(6890): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    talib/_ta_lib.c(7080): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    talib/_ta_lib.c(7262): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    talib/_ta_lib.c(7444): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    talib/_ta_lib.c(7449): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    talib/_ta_lib.c(7607): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, 

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\ta-lib\c\lib /LIBPATH:c:\programming\bot\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310 /LIBPATH:c:\programming\bot\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64 ta_libc_cdr.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__ta_lib build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\talib/_ta_lib.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.exp
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLBREAKAWAY_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLEVENINGSTAR
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLSEPARATINGLINES_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLDRAGONFLYDOJI
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_SetOptInputParamReal
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLMORNINGDOJISTAR_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_T3_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLSHOOTINGSTAR_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_ADD
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MA_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLKICKING
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MINUS_DM
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDL3WHITESOLDIERS
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLTRISTAR_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_HT_SINE
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MAMA
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_VAR
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLSPINNINGTOP_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLUPSIDEGAP2CROWS_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_COSH_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MININDEX
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLRISEFALL3METHODS
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLPIERCING_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_BOP_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_AROON_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_TRANGE_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLHARAMI
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_EXP
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_SUB_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_SetUnstablePeriod
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_FuncTableAlloc
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLONNECK
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLKICKING_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDL3OUTSIDE
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLDRAGONFLYDOJI_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_WCLPRICE_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MEDPRICE
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLONNECK_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLLADDERBOTTOM_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_LINEARREG_ANGLE_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_ACOS
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MINMAXINDEX_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MFI
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MINMAX
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_RSI_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_GroupTableFree
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLUPSIDEGAP2CROWS
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLTASUKIGAP
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_NATR
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLDOJISTAR
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_HT_PHASOR_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_WMA
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_Shutdown
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLSHORTLINE_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_GetFuncHandle
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_FuncTableFree
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_ParamHolderFree
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_MAVP
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDL3LINESTRIKE_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLCONCEALBABYSWALL_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_SAR
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLHIGHWAVE_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLMARUBOZU_Lookback
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_ADOSC
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLMARUBOZU
    _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_SAR_Lookback

    build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 339 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\programming\bot\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n7ad74zp\\ta-lib_1088777ae08747e18e950c7d1e1c3643\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n7ad74zp\\ta-lib_1088777ae08747e18e950c7d1e1c3643\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-us4n0edm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\programming\bot\include\site\python3.10\TA-Lib' Check the logs for full command output
```

I've had to delete some errors to fit this to 30000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by just doing a direct install from my downloads folder doing a pip install to the absolute path of [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) my download on here. Then reinstalled my requirements now I have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

- download latest https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ edition, didn't select anything just the default install
- Followed these instructions
  'Download ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip and unzip to C:\ta-lib.

This is a 32-bit binary release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library. Some unofficial (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here for reference:

Download and Unzip ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip
Move the Unzipped Folder ta-lib to C:
Download and Install Visual Studio Community (2015 or later)
Remember to Select [Visual C++] Feature
Build TA-Lib Library
From Windows Start Menu, Start [VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]
Move to C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc
Build the Library nmake'

- in another command prompt did 'pip install TA-lib' (finally worked - been struggling the whole day)